# Gsap + Next js section slide on scroll vertically

Tags: reactjs, next.js, slider, gsap, slide

I'm currently working on a project that involves creating a section animation using GSAP and Next.js. I've been searching for a solution, but I haven't found one that fits my requirements.

I'm looking to replicate a section animation similar to this example: [link to example](https://booked.webflow.io/#scroll). You can find the animation below the "About" section on the webpage. The desired effect is that as the user scrolls, the section's image and content smoothly slide vertically, creating an engaging visual experience.

I've attempted to implement this animation using GSAP and Next.js, but I've hit some roadblocks. If anyone has experience with a similar animation or can provide any guidance, code examples, or alternative approaches, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm open to using alternative frameworks or libraries if they better suit this animation requirement.

Thank you for your time and assistance!